# IIS Rewrite rule, url modify himself

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I have write a rewrite rule to redirect an incoming request to the correct server.

Here my web.config :

```
        <rules>
            <rule name="ToMonceau">
                <match url="test/(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://10.5.5.83/{R:1}" />
                <serverVariables>
                    <set name="HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="{HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" />
                    <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="" />
                </serverVariables>
            </rule>
        </rules>
        <outboundRules>
            <rule name="AddPrefix" preCondition="IsText" enabled="true">
                <match filterByTags="A, Img, Link, Script" pattern="(http://10.5.5.83/mantis/)?(/mantis/)?(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{URL}" pattern="(test/mantis)/(.*)" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" value="./{R:3}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="RestoreAcceptEncofing" preCondition="NeedsRestoringAcceptEncoding">
                <match serverVariable="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" pattern="^(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" value="{HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" />
            </rule>
            <preConditions>
                <preCondition name="IsText">
                    <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/(.+)" />
                </preCondition>
                <preCondition name="NeedsRestoringAcceptEncoding">
                    <add input="{HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" pattern=".*" />
                </preCondition>
            </preConditions>
        </outboundRules>
```

My problem when I go to http://localhost/test/mantis (my server hosts a mantis here), the url change automatically to http://localhost/mantis/, I have to put again the "test/" and it change to http://localhost/mantis/login_page.php. I reput again "test/" and this time the login's page of mantis shown.

The problem continue when I try to log in, the url changes continously by removing the "test/" part.

If I go directly to my mantis without the redirect (http://10.5.5.83/mantis) everything is working like a charm.

What am I missing in my rule to do it correctly ?

I take the exemple here with mantis but I have the same problem on every sites host by different server.

Thanks in advance and sorry if my english is not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Go to IIS manager and click on URL rewrite:

1. Keep pattern .*
2. Action type should be Rewrite
3. Rewrite URL: http://yourdesiredurl/{R:0}

Comment: It doesn't work. My initial request is http://localhost/test/mantis and I want to redirect to http://10.5.5.83/mantis (with your solution, it's redirect to http://10.5.5.83/test/mantis) and come back by changing my url to http://localhost/mantis and I want to have http://localhost/test/mantis